# Symfony2: Multi tenant roles in FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, multi-tenant, fosuserbundle

So I'm delevoping an application with multiple clients.  Users could access more than one client with different roles in each case.  For instance, User A has **ROLE_XX** for **Client C1**, but **ROLE_YY** for **Client C2**.

As far as I know, *FosUserBundle* stores the roles for a user in the column **roles** (default table **fos_user**), so this structure is not suitable for my needs.

I've read the documentation realated with [roles management](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md), but there is nothing related, so I guess it's a feature beyond the scope of *FosUserBundle*?.

So I was thinking about creating an addional table which relates them (client, user, role), but since I'm no FOS expert at all, I really don't know if this is the correct way to go.  Or maybe I'm missing something.  Any tip is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirements exceed what Symfony's security roles system provides. You will need to either maintain an ACL or encapsulate your access control logic in a custom security voter. I recently wrote about the latter approach here:

http://kriswallsmith.net/post/15994931191/symfony2-security-voters

Comment: Yes! Looks like this is the right way to implement it.  Thanks, I'll give it a try!